# como saber si un polyline se esta mostrando en el mapa?

Tags: android, google-maps

mi proyecto de android contiene algunos marcadores, mi idea es que al hacer click en un marcador se genere una polyline hasta el marcador desde mi posicion actual, el problema que tengo, es como saber si la polyline existe para borrarla y agregar la nueva polyline, espero puedan ayudarme

esto es lo que tengo, no se como hacer hacer el if que determine si existe el polyline

```
 map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                if (!location.hasLocationEnabled()) {
                    // ask the user to enable location access
                    SimpleLocation.openSettings(RutaHasta.this);
                }

                LatLng marcador= new LatLng(marker.getPosition().latitude,marker.getPosition().longitude);
                LatLng posicion=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

                Polyline polyline=map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(marcador,posicion).geodesic(true).color(Color.GREEN).width(7));

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Con el codigo actual dibuja el polyline?

Comment: Si borro Polyline Polyline y dejo lo que está después del igual, se muestra

Comment: El problema es que si borro lo q te mencione, pierdo la función remove del polyline